# Remove Quotes Between String in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I need to remove all Quotes between 2 strings, like this example :

`"text":" bla bla bla bla bla " bla bla bla " bla bla " bla bla ","user"`

I have tried something like this (,"text":"[^"]*)"+(.*)([^"]*","user") but only replace the first occurrence .

Could you please help me, I am a little lost with this.

Comment: I would just remove them all and then re-add them where they are supposed to be - begin/end and around commas; assuming this is csv type file.  I know it's powerful, but regex is not very intuitive and I reserve its usage to only the most complicated and unpredictable conversions.

Comment: Please [edit] and show some example before and after text. At the moment your question is unclear.

Comment: Since you can remove the first occurrence, why not "Replace All" a few times until there are no more replacements? That's what I'd do: inelegant, but practical.

Answer (score 0):

regex: `(?<!^)(?<![,:])"(?![,:])(?!$)`

Will replace any `"` that isn't the `^`beginning of line, `$`end of line, or surrounded on any side by `[,:]`comma or colon.

Should be good unless I misunderstood what you were trying to do. If you have more delimiters than `[,:]` just add them into the two groups in the regex.